# When deploying Jasper Reports getting error message

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

Hi I created a simple report using iReport 4.5.1 and when I tried to deploy the report in JasperSoft (Ver 4.5) I am getting the following error message even thought I am selecting the correct JRXML file

**The selected JRXML could not be parsed. You might have selected the wrong file.**

What could be the issue.

I am using iReport designer to design my reports.
Database: Oracle 11g 
I have created a Data Source in JaseperSoft  - test connection successfull
I am getting the error message only when I click the browse button to upload the JRXML file when i tried to upload a report file...

Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occur when attempting to deploy a report that uses stored procedures.

You can find [this issue](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=97133) at http://jasperforge.org.

[This article](http://brianburridge.com/2006/06/04/how-to-call-stored-procedures-from-jasper-reports/) is about how to call stored procedures from JasperReports.

Comment: Hi Alex... Thanks for your response... The JasperReport designed using iReport 4.5 using stored procedures part is working fine for me (I am able to run the report from the designer no issues there).... the Issue is only when I try to deploy the report in JasperReport Enterprise Server (trial version) that is when I am getting this error message. I tried deploying the a parent report with sub report and without sub report both the time I was getting the same error message

Comment: UPDATE: The above issue is resolved by connecting the iReport 4.5 designer to the JasperServer. Once the connection is established I was able to deploy directly from the designer.so far so good... 
But when I execute the report in the JasperServer I get the following error message

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the 'plsql' language.  

which again points me back to your earlier comment... is there a step by step instruction to resolve this issue...

Answer (score 1):

Try to deploy the report using the jdeploy tool on https://sourceforge.net/projects/jaspertools/?source=directory

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
By default JasperSoft® Studio tries to save and upload the JRXML's in the latest possile JRXML version which may not be compatible with the parser on the server side. You can configure the version used by the studio. Go to Window > Preferences > Jaspersoft Studio > Compatibility and in the Source .jrxml version set the version to 6.2.1. Then open your reports, do a minor change and re-save it. This should re-generate the JRXML that is compatible with previous JasperReports version. You can also set the same compatibility setting on project level by right clicking on the project folder in the Project Explorer > Properties > Jaspersoft Studio > Compatibility

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/error-message-selected-jrxml-could-not-be-parsed-when-trying-update-jrxml-files-tibco

Answer (score -1):

I have created an automatic build option for maven reports. Anyone that is interested please read: http://the-consultants-blog.blogspot.be/2013/06/deploy-jasperreports-with-maven.html

It might come in handy with deployment problems or with mass deployment of jrxmls.